# is there a way to persist all the values in a @Entity Class with @onetomany relation in a single table using JPA?

Tags: java, jpa

I'm new to JPA and still learning
I have one doubt/problem  related to JPA
and I'm too confused to find any solution can someone please let me know if I can do any workaround to get this done or point me to some documentation if it is possible.

My json structure:

```
{
"Action":"txn",
"Rec_count":"1",
"Page_count":"1",
"Records":
               [
               {
                "Pan":"abcd",
                "CRN":"cedf"},
                {
                "Pan":"1234",
                "CRN":"sfdg"}
                ]
}
```

Now if I want to give `@Id` for the *CRN* field and store all the values i.e., *action*, *rec_count*, *page_count*, *pan* and *CRN* in the same table and iteration of the array (two rows in the above case),
can that be accomplished or there is no way to do that?

Because `@Embeddable` can be used to store everything in same table but you can't assign `@id` to the embeddable class.

The entity class

```
import lombok.*;
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.List;
@Table(name="GET_RECORDS")
@ToString
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
@Entity
public class entityClass{
    private String Action;
    private int Rec_cnt;
    private String Page_count;
    @OnetoMany
    private List<Records> records;
}
```

And I tried creating a Records class as

```
import lombok.*;
import javax.persistence.*;
@ToString
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
@embeddable
public class Records{
    @Id
    @NotNull
    private String CRN;
    @NotNull
    private int PAN;
}
```

I'm getting the error `onetomany attribute value type should not be embeddable`

Please let me know if there is any way to do this ?

Comment: You can use the `@ElementCollection` annotation instead of `@OnetoMany` to overcome the error, but I don't think you can avoid jpa from creating an extra table to hold the Records

Comment: Embeddable only works with one-to-one. Why do you want to do that? Having two tables is the purpose of a relational database. If you want tot store hierarchical documents checkout MongoDB